# ConcurrentSkipListMap into infinity loop with custom compare in descendingMap , Is that a java bug?

Tags: java

I'm very confused, Is that a bug?

I test it on windows zulu-openjdk-1.8, zulu-open-openjdk-11 adopt-16 debian openjdk-11-jdk they have same result.

**Windows Zulu-OpenJDK 8**
openjdk version "1.8.0_302"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.56.0.21-CA-win64) (build 1.8.0_302-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 8.56.0.21-CA-win64) (build 25.302-b08, mixed mode)

**Windows Zulu-OpenJDK 11**
openjdk version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu11.50+19-CA (build 11.0.12+7-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu11.50+19-CA (build 11.0.12+7-LTS, mixed mode)

**debian 10 + openjdk-11-jdk**
openjdk version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+7-post-Debian-2deb10u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.12+7-post-Debian-2deb10u1, mixed mode, sharing)

**Windows AdoptOpenJDK 16**
openjdk version "16.0.2" 2021-07-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-16.0.2+7 (build 16.0.2+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-16.0.2+7 (build 16.0.2+7, mixed mode, sharing)

```java
public class CSLMTest {

    private static class Entity {

        public int i;

        public Entity(int i) {
            this.i = i;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ConcurrentSkipListMap<Entity, Integer> map = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<>((o1, o2) -> {
            if (o1 == o2) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                int i = o1.i - o2.i;
                return i == 0 ? 1 : i;
            }
        });

        map.put(new Entity(1), 1);
        map.put(new Entity(1), 2);
        map.put(new Entity(1), 3);
        map.put(new Entity(1), 4);
        map.put(new Entity(1), 5);

        System.out.println(">> --------------------------------------------");

        for (Map.Entry<Entity, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey().i + " -> " + entry.getValue());
        }

        System.out.println(">> --------------------------------------------");

        for (Map.Entry<Entity, Integer> entry : map.descendingMap().entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey().i + " -> " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Output is different:

The first part is correct as I expect:

```
>> --------------------------------------------
1 -> 1
1 -> 2
1 -> 3
1 -> 4
1 -> 5
>> --------------------------------------------
```

Then the desc part has different result as far as I seen:

```
1 -> 5
1 -> 4
1 -> 3
1 -> 2
1 -> 1
# jvm exit
# working fine as expect
# java16 has much more chance got this result like 40%
```

```
1 -> 5
1 -> 4
1 -> 3
1 -> 2
1 -> 1
1 -> 5
1 -> 4
1 -> 3
1 -> 2
1 -> 1
# repeat infinity
```

```
1 -> 3
1 -> 5
1 -> 4
1 -> 3
1 -> 5
1 -> 4
1 -> 3
1 -> 5
# repeat infinity
```

```
1 -> 5
1 -> 4
1 -> 3
1 -> 2
1 -> 5
1 -> 4
1 -> 3
1 -> 2
# repeat infinity
```

```
1 -> 5
1 -> 4
1 -> 5
1 -> 4
1 -> 5
1 -> 4
1 -> 5
1 -> 4
# repeat infinity
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `Comparator` is broken. The JavaDoc for [`Comparator#compare()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,T)) states

> The implementor must ensure that sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x)) for all x and y.

But your comparator implementation

```
Comparator<Entity> cmp = (o1, o2) -> {
    if (o1 == o2) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        int i = o1.i - o2.i;
        return i == 0 ? 1 : i;
    }
};
```

returns 1 for two different `Entity` objects that have the same `i` value.

`ConcurrentSkipListMap` works correctly when you pass it a correct `Comparator` implementation. The behaviour with a broken `Comparator` is not specified.

Comment: I see , Is there any way to keep sort but don't override if not same ? ( That broken Comparator used for keep module order but not override if they has default priority) clearly the comparator only working in put not in entrySet , if I return o1.priority() - o2.priority() they will replace each other

Comment: The "best" solution depends very much on your actual requirements. Guava's [`Multimap`s](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multimap) for example are especially designed for the case "one key, multiple values"